# Problem about the upper bound of the modulus of a root of a monic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ If $z \in \mathbb C$ is a root of the monic polynomial $t^n+a_1t^{n-1}+....+a_n \in \mathbb C[t]$ , then show that $| z |\leq max\{ 1, |a_1|+|a_2|+...+|a_n|\} .$

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ Actually, I did think of the fact that when $| z| \geq 1$ , then I can construct a function including a complex root $z$ such that we can get the maximum value of $| z|$ from there.

Another thought came into my mind, i.e. by using the $\mathbf {Viete's}$ formula about adding all possible permutations of roots , then the upper bound other than $1$ is obtained on right side by triangular in-equality .

A small hint is warmly appreciated.

Comment: depending on what you know -- consider the Companion matrix with this monic polynomial, and apply Gerschgorin Discs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $z^{n}+a_1z^{n-1}+...+a_n=0$. If $|z| \leq 1$ then the conclusion is trivially true. Suppose $|z| >1$. Then $|z|^{n}=|(a_1z^{n-1}+...+a_n)|\leq |z|^{n-1} (|a_1|+|a_3|+...|a_n|)$. Divide by $|z|^{n-1}$.

Comment: Does the above proved theorem have a name. Where can I find it in textbooks?

Comment: I do not know any name for it but it is a standard exercise in books, @user842451