# Showing the root of a monic polynomial using linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose $p(z):\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n$, want to show that the magnitude of all root is less than $R=\sqrt{1+|a_{n-1}|^2+\dots +|a_0|^2}$. I wanted to work out a proof of this problem using some facts from linear algebra.

My idea is first to find some linear operator $T$ on this complex vector space and then look at $p(T)$ and use some facts about eigen values to show that all eigen values are less than $R$. But I have no luck how on to start the proof whatsoever, any kind of help and ideas is appreciated. Or the approach is not possible?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3552273/problem-about-the-upper-bound-of-the-modulus-of-a-root-of-a-monic-polynomial?rq=1

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Can you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread.

Comment: It seems the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is involved somehow.